# Filemaker: If statement multiples

Tags: filemaker

Filemaker Pro 13, using a windows 10 comp. The Database is used from both Mac and Windows computers.

I have a calculation field that detects the string-value of another field to define itself.

```
Field 1: Name   Field2: Position

If ( Field1 = "Bob" or "Joe" or "Carl" ; "Tech Assist")
If ( Field1 = "Susan" or "Hank" or "Alex" ; "Employee")
```

Filemaker only picks up on the first value of the If statement, in this example, "Bob" and "Susan". All others are left blank. 
Like so:

```
Name: Bob     Position: Tech Assist
Name: Joe     Position: ___________
```

How do I get Filemaker to view all possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fiddling, Big Boss and I figured it out. Seems a bit redundant:

```
If ( Field1 = "Bob or Field1 = "Joe" or Field1 = "Carl" ; "Tech Assist")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two problems with your attempt:

1. The test `Field1 = "Bob" or "Joe" or "Carl"` is evaluated as if you have written `(Field1 = "Bob") or ("Joe") or ("Carl")` - so it will only ever return true when Field1 = "Bob";
2. You cannot string two If() instructions together like that. Although
   you *could* nest them, you really should be using the Case()
   function here, say:

   ```
   Case ( 
   Field1 = "Bob" or Field1 = "Joe" or Field1 = "Carl" ; "Tech Assist" ;
   Field1 = "Susan" or Field1 = "Hank" or Field1 = "Alex" ; "Employee"
   )
   ```

The more serious problem here is that you are hard-coding *data* that will almost certainly change at some point into a calculation formula.

What you *should* have is a related table of Staff with fields for StaffID, Name and Position. Then, when you fill Field1 in this table with the appointed staff member's StaffID, the corresponding position will be taken from that staff member's record in the Staff table via a *relationship*.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively...

```
Case(

Not IsEmpty( FilterValues( List( "Bob" ; "Joe" ; "Carl" ) ; Field1 ) ) ; 
"Tech Assist" ; 

Not IsEmpty( FilterValues( List( "Susan" ; "Hank" ; "Alex" ) ; Field1 ) ) ; 
"Employee"

)
```

Answer (score 0):

A longer term solution would be to have a table of names and departments.  See the image in case it is not clear.

[Staff Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5dz.png)

Then you will build a relationship between Field1 in your current table and the "Name" field in the sample image.  From there, the relationship will output the name of the department so that you do not need if, else, or case.  Otherwise, you will find yourself updating this script every time there is a change to your roster or their roles in your company.  The relationship will also allow you to easily add new departments without the need to update this calculation.